# How do I test a python function which writes a json to disk?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I would like to know what is the best way write a test function (to be run using pytest) for the following short function which serialises a json.

```
import json
import os

def my_function(folder):
    my_dict = {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": "C"}
    with open(os.path.join(folder, 'my_json.json'), 'w') as f:
        json.dump(my_dict, f)
```

I would like the test to be written as a simple function (not as a method of a class inheriting from unittest.TestCase).

My current idea is

```
def test_my_function():
    my_function(folder)
    with open(os.path.join(folder, 'my_json.json'), 'r') as f:
        my_dict = json.load(f)
    assert my_dict == {"a": "A", "b": "B", "c": "C"}
```

I am wondering if there a more elegant way of testing this without touching the disk?

Comment: What are you trying to test?  Your function is basically a wrapper around `json.dump()`.  Are you trying to check if `json.dump()` works properly?

Comment: Yes you're right, I know it's basically a wrapper, but I need to have this wrapper function in my code and I'm wondering what is best testing practices in this case. Should I just not test this function? Let's put it this way: if I had a bigger function doing also other things and at some point dumping a json, how would I test that the json.dump happened correctly? Should I just skip the test because the json library will already have its own tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.dump()` is [tested by the maintainers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/test/test_json/test_dump.py) of the `json` package.

So, I don't think you have to test it yourself.

This is how they test the function without writing to disk:

```py
        sio = StringIO()
        self.json.dump({}, sio)
        self.assertEqual(sio.getvalue(), '{}')
```